# Is this an acceptable way to flatten a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm looking at a proper way to flatten something like this

```
a = [{'name': 'Katie'}, {'name': 'Katie'}, {'name': 'jerry'}]
```

having

```
d = {}
```

Using a double map like this:

```
map(lambda x: d.update({x:d[x]+1}) if x in d else d.update({x:1}),map(lambda x: x["name"] ,a))
```

I get the result i want:

```
>>> d
{'jerry': 1, 'Katie': 2}
```

But I feel it could be done better..not with list comprehensions tho , I feel that's what we have map reduce.

Comment: can there be more than one key, or is it always 'name'?

Comment: always name ... i just want to count duplicated names coming in that format... if you know what i mean

Comment: has any of the answers solved your problem sufficiently?

Answer (score 8):

I don't really like your solution because it is hard to read and has sideeffects.

For the sample data your provided, using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (which is a subclass of the built-in dictionary) is a better approach.

```
>>> Counter(d['name'] for d in a)
Counter({'Katie': 2, 'jerry': 1})
```

Comment: Also, one last q, when you mean side effects are you referring to violating the functional programming approach by modifying a variable (d in this case) outside the scope?

Comment: @JeronimoGarcia, in python unless you are using what is in the container don't create one, i.e  don't  `my_list=[];[my_list.append(I + foo ) for i in blah]`

Comment: I meant that your lambda function returns `None` and that your call to `map` returns `[None, None, None]` but you never use either of that return values, but solely use the map for its sideeffect of updating the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Counter and keep it functional:

```
In [46]: from collections import  Counter

In [47]: from operator import itemgetter

In [48]: Counter(map(itemgetter("name") ,a))
Out[48]: Counter({'Katie': 2, 'jerry': 1})
```

For python 2 you would use `itertools.imap` :

```
Counter(itertools.imap(itemgetter("name") ,a))
```

Comment: Aren't comprehensions preferred to `map` - see BDFL's [opinion](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: @AChampion, map is faster and widely used in python, the main argument from what I see in your link  is preparing a lambda which I rarely use, if I cannot use map without resorting to a lambda then I rarely do. I think `map(float, lst)` is as readable as `[float(s) for s in lst]`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case `reduce()` would be more appropriate then `map()`:

```
>>> def count_names(d, x):
...     d[x['name']] = d.get(x['name'], 0) + 1
...     return d
...
>>> reduce(count_names, a, {})
{'jerry': 1, 'Katie': 2}
```

Comment: especially the default argument on get() which i didn't know it was possible!

Answer (score 1):

Again using Counter, but extracting the dictionary.

```
>>> dict(Counter([i['name'] for i in a]))
{'Katie': 2, 'jerry': 1}
```

Here's a more convoluted method using groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

>>> dict((name, len(list(totals))) for name, totals in groupby([i["name"] for i in a]))
{'Katie': 2, 'jerry': 1}
```

Comment: why not `dict(Counter(i['name'] for i in a))` if you wanted a regular dict?

Comment: I new there must have been a better way.  I'm surprised there isn't a `.to_dict()` method for Counter.

Comment: @Alexander well, a Counter *is-a* dict, so I would not expect such a method.

Comment: subclassed from a dict, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
val = defaultdict(int)
for names in a:
    val[names['name']] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

for loop is your friend :)

```
a = [{'name': 'Katie'}, {'name': 'Katie'}, {'name': 'jerry'}]
result = {}
for data in a:
    if data['name'] not in result:
         result[data['name']] = 0
    result[data['name']] += 1
print result
```